# Implementing RequireJS on an existing app

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

With the scope of having the javascript side of an existing app, better structured, easy to manage/understand and better management of scripts that need to run for different parts of the site, I decided to try and implement RequireJS as a solution.

I also use grunt, and I took advantage of the [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) existing module, to manage it all in one place.

Grunt

```
requirejs: {
    options: {
        baseUrl: "./",
        mainConfigFile: "<%= project.scripts %>/build.js",
        name: "<%= project.bowerDir %>/almond/almond",
        out: "<%= project.scripts %>/main.min.js"
    },

    debug: {
        options: {
            optimize: 'none'
        }
    },

    production: {
        options: {
            optimize: 'uglify2'
        }
    }
},
```

build.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/",

    // automatically require on page load in debug mode
    deps: ['assets/scripts/main'],
    //deps: ['main'],

    // automatically require this for production build
    // insertRequire: ['assets/scripts/main'],

    paths: {
        "bower" : "../../../bower_components",
        "module": "../modules",

        "jquery"               : "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "jquery.ui"            : "assets/scripts/vendor/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
        "jquery.ui.touch-punch": "assets/scripts/vendor/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min",
        "lazyload"             : "bower_components/jquery.lazyload/jquery.lazyload",

        "swfobject"            : "assets/scripts/vendor/swfobject",
        "cookie"               : "assets/scripts/vendor/jquery.cookie",
        "query"                : "assets/scripts/vendor/jquery.query",
    }
}).call(this);

// Load the main app module to start the app
// requirejs(["app", "module/home"]);
```

main.js

```
define([
    'jquery', 'jquery.ui', 'jquery.ui.touch-punch',
    'lazyload', 'swfobject', 'cookie', 'query'
    ], function (require) {

    'use strict';

    $(function () {
        alert('main.');
        // ....
    });

});
```

So, I got to the point where I invoke my build.js (development env... read this article: [Grunt.js and Require.js - compiling with r.js](http://blog.noort.be/2013/02/07/grunt-js-and-require-js-compiling-with-r-js.html))...

```
<script data-main="/assets/scripts/build" src="/assets/scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

So, the `build.js` is loaded, and then the `main.js` also, and the `alert` executes. So far, so good... now comes the doubts:

- I can't seem to understand how to work with dependencies (from `jquery` to `cookie` and `query`). How can I expect them to be already loaded? Because, on my `main.js` I will invoke those libraries, but I get errors due to the fact that they're not loaded.
- Let's say for `/articles` I have `articles.js`, for `/profiles` I have `profiles.js`. How will I manage to process each `.js` according to the pages I need/want to? `main.js` is the common file, but there are separate `.js` files for each module in the web.
- Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you are just getting started with RequireJS I would pause and take a look at Browserify (http://browserify.org/). It takes the guess work out of everything (paths, shims, etc), by allowing you to simply write require statements like you would in NodeJS. `$ = require('jquery')` would be how you assign jQuery to the dollar sign so long as it's loaded via NPM in your node_modules. Want to use libs already written? `module.exports` what you're returning. It makes web components awesome. I haven't used RequireJS since I've found it.

Comment: @iamjpg thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look into it

Answer (score 3):

Within requirejs, you can specify dependancies for each shim. (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

So if file a.js depends on file b.js to exist prior to loading, you can specify a dependency on file a. Each time you require file a, it will first require file b.

Example:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "/",

// automatically require on page load in debug mode
deps: ['assets/scripts/main'],
//deps: ['main'],

// automatically require this for production build
// insertRequire: ['assets/scripts/main'],

paths: {
    "a"               : "assets/scripts/vendor/a",
    "b"                : "assets/scripts/vendor/b",
},
shim: {
    "a": {
        deps: ["b"]
    }
}

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide valid identifiers as arguments in the define callback (your entry point).
Demo with a shortened list:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery.ui',
    'cookie'

], function(
    $,
    jQueryUI,
    MyCookie

) {

    'use strict';

    alert( $ ); //your local jQuery
    jQueryUI.doSomething();
    MyCookie.fooBar( 'I was required' );

});
```

Identifier names are of your choice, but I'd suggest to stick to some conventions. There is more than that in require.js, but this could get you started.

Comment: I want other libraries (like the cookie one), to be loaded automatically, without having me invoking one by one, because there are a couple of them

Comment: "I want" is not a valid argument in JS programming. You can try to register them as globals on the first load, but it really depends on those libs themselves.